# Using Nan to create array in Node.js add-on code

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-addon

I'm writing Node add-on and using the **[nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan)** library as much as I can for writing the code. It's recommended by the Node project because it lets you write code that's compatible with different version of v8 and node.

However after looking through their [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/tree/master/doc) many times, I haven't found any guidance on handling of arrays in the nan API. For basic tasks like processing arrays passed as arguments by the Javascript code, or instantiating new array objects in the add-on and return it to Javascript code. Are we supposed to directly work with `v8::Array` API. I wished the [Nan::New](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/new.md) part of the API would have handled this better.

Have I missed something?

Comment: If you look at [the documentation they point to](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/io.js-3.0/d1/d83/classv8_1_1_data.html), `v8:Array` is an object. So for creating a new array, I'm fairly certain (I haven't messed around with Node addons in a while) you just do `Nan::New<v8:Array>()`. As for iterating over an array, I'm not sure.

Comment: Indeed. That worked. Makes the code better by not needing reference to isolate (as required when v8::Array is used directly). Thanks for the tip. If you post it as answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the V8 documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/io.js-3.0/d1/d83/classv8_1_1_data.html), you'll see that `v8::Array` is a subset of `v8::Object`. Given this, you can create an array with

```
Nan::New<v8::Array>();
```

You can reference the `v8::Array` documentation for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Searching for solutions to some related problems I have found [this repository](https://github.com/freezer333/nodecpp-demo) which has some very good working examples.

I'm just pointing out the Array related conversions here for quick reference.

**Receive array in arguments:**

```
Local<Array> array = Local<Array>::Cast(args[0]); //args[0] holds the first argument

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < array->Length(); i++ ) {
  if (Nan::Has(array, i).FromJust()) {
    //assuming the argument is an array of 'double' values, for any other type the following line will be changed to do the conversion
    double value = Nan::Get(array, i).ToLocalChecked()->NumberValue();

    Nan::Set(array, i, Nan::New<Number>(value + 1));
  }
}
```

**Return an array:**

```
//Assuming arr is an 'array' of 'double' values
Local<Array> a = New<v8::Array>(3);
Nan::Set(a, 0, Nan::New(arr[0]));
Nan::Set(a, 1, Nan::New(arr[1]));
Nan::Set(a, 2, Nan::New(arr[2]));

info.GetReturnValue().Set(a); //here 'info' is 'const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info' received in Nan Method defintion parameter
```

The specific solution can be found [here](https://github.com/freezer333/nodecpp-demo/blob/master/conversions_nan/basic_nan.cpp#L71).